# Html input with text and tag (optional)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm searching for a html input field with tags as optional with into the input.

With "tags" i mean this small badges like this plugin
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

The tags should be a list which I define before and all other inputs in the field are normal Text and no Tags. 
With a dropdown with the defined tags would be nice.All other functions was a nice feature but not required.

Have anyone a plugin with which I can do this? Normal js and jquery is also acceptable.

Here an example what i search http://puu.sh/uf6Yj/ae8ee28894.png

Comment: what is wrong with the plugin you linked to?

Comment: Use the plugin you linked to :)

Comment: @NatureShade i want to write normalen text AND tags in the input, the plugin only can display tags in the input and cant handle with normal text

Answer (score 0):

In html 5 you can declare any attribute, there is no limit.

```
<input type="text" data-tag="tag" data-text="text" data-order="1" />
```